# How can i add fixed nav bar switching animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created two navigation one at top other at page center. Code is working fine but i want add some some animation effects while nav switching i have tried adding `slideDown/Up` but they didn't made them much interactive like i want. Please help me how can i add a animation effect?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhai22/Eg4Dg/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()>2000){
            $("#nav02").css("position", "fixed");
            $("#nav02").css("top", 0);
            $("#nav01").hide();
        } else {
            $("#nav02").css("position", "relative");
            $("#nav01").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one may be it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop()>2000){
                $("#nav02").css("position", "fixed");
                $("#nav02").css("top", 0);
                $("#nav01").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#nav02").css("position", "relative");
                $("#nav01").slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you give me your website url

Comment: i have added the fiddle - you can check that in the question